# How to get array of images from network faster? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlrequest

Basically, I have an array of urls as strings, and as I loop through this array, if the element is a url for an image, I want to turn that url into a UIImage object and add it to another array. This is very slow though since I have to request the data for each URL. I've tried using dispatch_async as I show below but it doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

The key is that when I add these objects to my other array, whether they are images or something else they have to stay **in order**. Can anyone offer any guidance?

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
for (int i=0; i<[slides count]; i++){
        __block NSString *mediaURLString = [primaryPhoto objectForKey:@"url"];

        if ([self mediaIsVideo:mediaURLString]){
              ***some code***
        }
        else{ //if media is an image
            dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

                mediaURLString = [mediaURLString stringByAppendingString:@"?w=1285&h=750&q=150"];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaURLString];
                [mutableMedia addObject:url];
                NSURL *url = ((NSURL *)self.mediaItem);
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                NSURLResponse *response;
                NSError *error;
                NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:urlData];
                [mutableMedia replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:image];
            });
        }
    }
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(WebServiceCallMethod) withObject:nil];
```

and create one method like this

```
-(void)WebServiceCallMethod
{
                mediaURLString = [mediaURLString stringByAppendingString:@"?w=1285&h=750&q=150"];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaURLString];
                [mutableMedia addObject:url];
                NSURL *url = ((NSURL *)self.mediaItem);
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                NSURLResponse *response;
                NSError *error;
                NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:urlData];
                [mutableMedia replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:image];
}
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and don't use `+sendSynchronousRequest:...`  Try something like this instead:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for (int i=0; i<[slides count]; i++)
{
    __block NSString *mediaURLString = [primaryPhoto objectForKey:@"url"];
    if ([self mediaIsVideo:mediaURLString]){
        ***some code***
    }
    else
    {
        //if media is an image
        mediaURLString = [mediaURLString stringByAppendingString:@"?w=1285&h=750&q=150"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaURLString];
        [mutableMedia addObject:url];
        NSURL *url = ((NSURL *)self.mediaItem);
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
         ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
         {
             if (data.length && nil == connectionError)
             {
                 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                 [mutableMedia replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:image];
             }
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];
    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do stuff here that you want to have happen after all the images are loaded.
});
```

This will start asynchronous requests for all your URLs. When each request finishes, it will run its completion handler which will update your array, and when all requests have finished, the block in the `dispatch_group_notify` call will be executed.

This approach has the advantage that you can call it from the main thread, all individual completion blocks will be run on the main thread (thus ensuring thread-safety for the `mutableMedia` array (at least as far as this code goes)) and the final completion block will also be run on the main thread, so you can do whatever you need to update the UI directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty solution using dispatch lib. The code below should stand for itself.

The basic idea is that an array contains "input" objects which each will be "transformed" via an asynchronous unary task - one after the other. The final result of the whole operation is an array of the transformed objects.

Everything here is asynchronous. Every *eventual result* will be passed in a completion handler which is a block where the result is passed as a parameter to the call-site:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);
```

The asynchronous transform function is a block which takes the input as a parameter and returns a new object - via a completion handler:

```
typedef void (^unary_async_t)(id input, completion_t completion);
```

Now, the function `transformEach` takes the input values as an `NSArray` parameter *inArray*, the transform block as parameter *transform* and the completion handler block as parameter *completion*:

```
static void transformEach(NSArray* inArray, unary_async_t transform, completion_t completion);
```

The implementation is a follows:

```
static void do_each(NSEnumerator* iter, unary_async_t transform, 
  NSMutableArray* outArray, completion_t completion)
{
    id obj = [iter nextObject];
    if (obj == nil) {
        if (completion)
            completion([outArray copy]);
        return;
    }
    transform(obj, ^(id result){
        [outArray addObject:result];
        do_each(iter, transform, outArray, completion);
    });
}

static void transformEach(NSArray* inArray, unary_async_t transform, 
  completion_t completion) {
    NSMutableArray* outArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inArray count]];
    NSEnumerator* iter = [inArray objectEnumerator];
    do_each(iter, transform, outArray, completion);
}
```

And build and run the following example

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Example transform:
        unary_async_t capitalize = ^(id input, completion_t completion) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
               sleep(1);
                if ([input respondsToSelector:@selector(capitalizedString)]) {
                    NSLog(@"processing: %@", input);
                    NSString* result = [input capitalizedString];
                    if (completion)
                        completion(result);
                }
            });
        };


        transformEach(@[@"a", @"b", @"c"], capitalize, ^(id result){
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
        });
        sleep(10);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

will print this to the console:

```
2013-07-31 15:52:49.786 Sample2[1651:1603] processing: a
2013-07-31 15:52:50.789 Sample2[1651:1603] processing: b
2013-07-31 15:52:51.792 Sample2[1651:1603] processing: c
2013-07-31 15:52:51.793 Sample2[1651:1603] Result: (
    A,
    B,
    C
)
```

You can easily create a category for `NSArray` which implements, say a

`-(void) asyncTransformEachWithTransform:(unary_async_t)transform 
                              completion:(completion_t)completionHandler`;

method.

Have fun!  ;)

---

#### Edit:

IFF you ask how this applies to your problem:

The array of URLs is the input array. In order to create the transform block, simply wrap your *asynchronous* network request in an *asynchronous* method, say:

```
`-(void) fetchImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;`
```

Then wrap method `fetchImageWithURL:completion:` into a appropriate transform block:

```
 unary_async_t fetchImage = ^(id url, completion_t completion) {
    [self fetchImageWithURL:url completion:^(id image){
        if (completion) 
            completion(image);  // return result of fetch request
    }];
};
```

Then, somewhere in your code (possible a view controller) assuming you implemented the category for `NSArray`, and your array of urls is property `urls`:

```
// get the images
[self.urls asyncTransformEachWithTransform:fetchImage completion:^(id arrayOfImages) {
     // do something with the array of images
}];
```